# number formatting macro using xparse and pgfmathprintnumber not working for one option

Tags: xparse, pgfmath

I am trying to write a macro that prints numbers with a couple of options. The macro takes one optional argument that is the precision of the output and a starred version that attaches a unit to the number.

- `\printExpressionFormatted{expr}` should evaluate the expression and print the result
- `\printExpressionFormatted[2]{expr}` should evaluate the expression format the number to the given precision and print the result
- `\printExpressionFormatted*[2]{expr}` and attach the units.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\printExpressionFormatted{som}{
    \pgfmathparse{#3}
    \IfNoValueTF#2{\pgfmathresult}%
    {
        \pgfmathprintnumberto[/pgf/number format/fixed, precision=#2]{\pgfmathresult}{\myFormattedNumber}
        \IfBooleanTF#1{\myFormattedNumber~$\times~10^6 m^3$}{\myFormattedNumber}
    }
}


\begin{document}
\section{Testing}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Unformatted & \printExpressionFormatted{746234.4485} \\
Formatted   & \printExpressionFormatted[2]{746234.4485} \\
Formatted with units &  \printExpressionFormatted*[2]{746234.4485} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The second and third incarnations work fine, however the first option (no formatting)
generates the following error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>

 l.19 ...d & \printExpressionFormatted{746234.4485}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose the argument `#2` of `\IfNoValue` in curly brackets, otherwise when not set `#2` is essentially `-NoValue-` and only the first token gets eaten by the test.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tracingmacros=1
\DeclareDocumentCommand\printExpressionFormatted{som}{
    \pgfmathparse{#3}
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\pgfmathresult}%
    {
        \pgfmathprintnumberto[/pgf/number format/fixed, precision=#2]{\pgfmathresult}{\myFormattedNumber}
        \IfBooleanTF#1{\myFormattedNumber~$\times~10^6 m^3$}{\myFormattedNumber}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\section{Testing}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Unformatted & \printExpressionFormatted{746234.4485} \\
Formatted   & \printExpressionFormatted[2]{746234.4485} \\
Formatted with units &  \printExpressionFormatted*[2]{746234.4485} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```